# command line: Unable to access jarfile eps2pgf.jar

Tags: java, command-line, osx-mavericks, eps, pgf

I'm working with a Mac OSX version 10.9.5 and I am a complete newbie to using the command line and running java files in it.

I just downloaded the eps2pgf folder, I unzipped it and I downloaded JDK8.

However when I try to run the command (thats given in the manual) in my Terminal, I get the following error:

```
Unable to access jarfile eps2pgf.jar
```

The exact command I use is:

```
java -jar eps2pgf.jar Bifurcatiediagram.eps -o Bifurcatiediagram.pgf
```

So in total the command before I run it is (with what is automatically there as well):

```
mbpvanasteyaert:~ Aranka$ java -jar eps2pgf.jar Bifurcatiediagram.eps -o Bifurcatiediagram.pgf
```

What am I doing wrong? Should the eps2pgf unzipped folder be in a specific folder/directory or...?

Comment: you may need to supply a path to the jar if you're not in the directory containing the jar. From which directory are you running the java command?

Comment: From you prompt, it appears you are running this command from your home folder. And I assume the jar file is somewhere inside the unzipped folder. Can you look for it in there? Also, is that unzipped folder straight under your home folder, or is it in the Downloads folder?

Comment: @pb2q I'm guessing I'm running it from my Home directory (called Aranka) I'm not really an expert in command lines so I honestly don't know for sure... I tried putting the folder name in front of  `eps2pgf.jar` so: `~/eps2pgf-0.7.0/eps2pgf.jar` and then I get this error: `Error: Unable to access jarfile /Users/Aranka/eps2pgf-0.7.0/eps2pgf.jar`

Comment: @RealSkeptic right now it is in my home folder as well as some other folders because I thought that might have been the problem, but I didn't know where to put it...

Comment: But where is the eps2pgf.jar file? Try using Spotlight to search for it, then reveal it in finder, then Get Info on it, then look for its full path.

Comment: @RealSkeptic it is under `Aranka/eps2pgf-0.7.0/eps2pgf.jar`

Comment: Oh wait I just looked at the info-bar when clicking once on it... In the Get Info it sais: Where: /Users/Aranka/eps2pgf-0.7.0